# group boxplot histogramming

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization, boxplot

I would like to group my data and to plot the boxplot for all the groups. There are many questions and answer about that, my problem is that I want to group by a continuos variable, so I want to histogramming my data.

Here what I have done. My data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.chisquare(5, size=100000)
y = np.random.normal(size=100000) / (0.05 * x + 0.1) + 2 * x

f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, '.', alpha=0.05)
plt.show()
```

[image: scatter]

I want to study the behaviour of `y` (location, width, ...) as a function of `x`. I am not interested in the distribution of `x` so I will normalized it.

```
f, ax = plt.subplots()
xbins = np.linspace(0, 25, 50)
ybins = np.linspace(-20, 50, 50)
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(y, x, bins=(ybins, xbins))
norm = np.sum(H, axis = 0)
H /= norm
ax.pcolor(xbins, ybins, np.nan_to_num(H), vmax=.4)
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram]

I can plot histogram, but I want boxplot

```
binning = np.concatenate(([0], np.sort(np.random.random(20) * 25), [25]))
idx = np.digitize(x, binning)
data_to_plot = [y[idx == i] for i in xrange(len(binning))]
f, ax = plt.subplots()

midpoints = 0.5 * (binning[1:] + binning[:-1])
widths = 0.9 * (binning[1:] - binning[:-1])

from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter
majorLocator   = MultipleLocator(2)

ax.boxplot(data_to_plot, positions = midpoints, widths=widths)
ax.set_xlim(0, 25)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(majorLocator)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('median(y)')
plt.show()
```

[image: boxplot]

Is there an automatic way to do that, like `ax.magic(x, y, binning)`? Is there a better way to do that? (Have a look to https://root.cern.ch/root/html/TProfile.html for example, which plot the mean and the error of the mean as error bars)

In addition, I want to minize the memory footprint (my real data are much more than 100000), I am worried about `data_to_plot`, is it a copy?